# Unable to parse json data written directly by python json.dump()

Tags: python, json

I have the following function:

```
def readTable(self,reference_name):

    p  = self.base_path + reference_name + ".txt"

    if os.path.exists(p):
        print p
    else:
        print "oops"

    f = open(p, "r")
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    self.main_table =  data
```

That tells me the file does indeed exist, and is trying to read my txt file that contains json.

The json is written by the following call:

```
def writeTable(table,reference_name):

    with open(reference_name + ".txt","w") as text_file:
        json.dump(table, text_file)
```

Yet when I go to `readTable` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 1069, in doIt
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd_vars.py", line 341, in evaluateExpression
    Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

And the data in the file looks like this:

```
[12.7451, 0.774784, 3.422666, 1.21522, 0.918463, 630.693, 6.37, 6.263, 2479.94, 555.475, 24.3585, 6.619372, 8.58075, 1.12385, 1.555879, 7.75208, 274.995, 14458.4, 3.8407999999999998, 68.25702, 119.12, 104.5, 1105.223, 10.1126, u'', 15.8013, 3.7115, 7.612444, 0.71116, 3.34583, 45.645, 3.6949300000000003, 57.5855, 8.22703, 1.3449900000000001, 26.80494, 34.639, 2.95794, 30.6675, u'', 12.86649]
```

Comment: what does your json look like?, is it well formed? you can check through jsonlint.com

Comment: Your JSON has a `u''` in it, which is invalid.  Are you sure you created the file using only `json.dump`?

Comment: You do **not** have JSON in that file. You wrote a **Python** list to it, you have `u'',` in the list. That file was *not* created with `json.dump()`, but with `f.write(str(table))`.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you. I had forgotten to rerun a bit of python code in my ipy after changing it. Please post as answer.